# injective dimension and Ext

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local commutative ring with a unit. $M$ is a finitely generated module. In the article "Minimal Injective Resolutions" by Robert Fossum, he mentioned it is standard that

$$\operatorname{id}_R(M)=\sup\{i\mid \operatorname{Ext}^i_R(R/m,M)\neq 0 \}$$

why is it the case? I mean $\operatorname{id}_R(M)$ is definitely $\sup\{i\mid\operatorname{Ext}^i(N,M)\}$ in which $N$ ranges through all modules. How can we reduce it to the case $R/m$?

Does it mean $M$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{Ext}^1(R/m,M)=0\,$? I mean if this is true, the original problem is trivial.

Thank you

Comment: I do not think the statement that $M$ is injective if $Ext^1_R(R/m,M) = 0$ is true. For instance, take a regular local ring $R$ of dimension at least $2$ and $M = R$. Then $Ext^1_R (R/m, R) = 0$ as the depth of R is at least $2$. But $R$ is not injective an $R$-injective module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(R,m) is Noetherian local ring.

**I am very sorry for the wrong argument.thanks for the comment above.it shows that $M$ may not injective if $Ext^1(k,M)=0$.We only can reduce to the case $M$ is injective iff $Ext^i(k,M)=0.\forall i>0$.**

Definition:If $M$ is an $R$ module,$p\in Spec(R)$ is called associate prime if $\exists x\in M$ such that $ann(x)=p$.

Denote $ass(M)$ is the set of associated prime ideals.

lemma1:for any nonzero module M,$ass(M)$ is not empty.

corollary1:for any finite generated module $M$,there is a filtration:$M_0=0\subset M_1\subset M_2\subset …\subset M_n=M$ such that $\forall i=0,1,2,…,n-1.\exists p_i\in Spec R$ such that $M_{i+1}/M_i\cong R/p_i$.(In fact,$p_i\in Supp(M)$)

Lemma2:if $N$ is finite generated and $Ext^1(R/p,M)=0 ,\forall p\in Supp(N)$,then $Ext^1(N,M)=0$.

**Lemma3:Let $M$ be a finite generated $R$ module.if $p$ is a prime ideal different from $m$,and $Ext^{n+1}(R/q,M)=0，\forall q\in V(p)-p$,then $Ext^n(R/p,M)=0$.
(Hint:select $x\in m-p$，then there is a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow R/p \xrightarrow x R/p \rightarrow R/(x,p)\rightarrow 0$.
Remark $Supp(R/(x,p)\subset V(p)-p$.**

Then you can prove $id M=sup\{i\mid Ext^i(k,M)\ncong 0\}$ by using Lemma 3 repeatedly.

Comment: If all the prime ideals has this property,then use lemma2.

Comment: Of course Baer's criterion.

Comment: @LongLêThiên such as：Relative homological algebra.（Enoch and Jenda）

Comment: @LongLêThiên yesterday I have a wrong hinit.I say consider prime ideals $V(p)=m$,in this case $p=m$.I am so sorry!I feel so ashamed!

Comment: @LongLêThiên thanks，